# What does "instrument" exactly mean in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Recently I am learning an open source systems monitoring and alerting toolkit [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/).

I read the online documentation carefully. There is a glossary named "**Instrument**" (instrumentation or instrumenting) in Prometheus. For me it's not very easy to understand. Perhaps it's because this word has so many different meanings when I searched in my dictionary, and none of them are suitable to help me understand it in Prometheus context (My native language is not English).

Could someone explain its meaning in a simple way? And what is "instrumentation" for and why we need it in Prometheus?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Did the below answers not answer your question? I think they do - you should accept the one you find answers it best.

Answer (score 9):

In the context of Prometheus, instrumentation is the use of a library in an application's code base in order to expose and update metrics about it for a Prometheus instance to scrape.

For example, one could use the [Prometheus Python client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) (contains example) in their python based application to expose metrics about it to be scraped.

Answer (score 6):

In the Prometheus context, instrumentation is adding code to create and update metrics inside your application. Here's a simple [Java guide](https://www.robustperception.io/instrumenting-java-with-prometheus/).

It's needed in Prometheus as it's the best way to get the data that you'll then graph and alert on in Prometheus itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Prometheus, instrumentation means adding and exposing your own custom metrics. Say, you want to know how many people are clicking on a button, then you can create a counter metric for this purpose. Tracking the number of API calls being made on an API is another place where you can add and expose your own custom metric.
Prometheus provides you different client libraries which can be used to instrument your application depending on the language you're using in your application/service.